# Как изменить код ответа сервера?

Tags: php

Сервера возвращает `Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251`, а нужно чтобы вернул без указанию кодировки.

`header(Content-Type: text/html)` так не работает.

Comment: В чем выражено "не работает" ? И почему в header строка не в кавычках ?

Comment: это здесь так, на само деле `<?php header('Content-Type: text/plain'); ?>`. не работает, то есть возвращает `Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251`, а нужно `Content-Type: text/html`

Comment: А зачем вам без кодировки ? У вас небось в настройках web-сервера указана кодировка, вот он и ставит ее. Лучше явно указать ту кодировку которая требуется, а не указывать ее вообще

Comment: мне нужно для подтверждение некого действия, а в настройках в каком именно файле указана кодировка? `Debian 7`

Comment: Если вы хотите что бы кодировки не было, вам надо пересмотреть все настройки вашего web сервера что бы нигде не была указана кодировка, и если web-сервер после этого стартует и кодировки еще не окажется в каком нибудь .htaccess то возможно он ее наконец то не укажет. хотя php может от себя что нибудь добавить ...

Comment: средствами `php` этого добиться нельзя? не ковыряясь в настройках

Comment: Вот этого я точно не знаю. что я знаю точно, так это то, что апач просто обожает дописывать кодировку сам. И отказывается от этого только когда скрипт явно указал какую нибудь кодировку сам. Что же у вас там интересно на другом конце, что оно не понимает строку с кодировкой.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/270273/

Comment: Вот извращенцы то, кодировка им не нравится ... Попробуйте для начала без php. попложите html страницу и посмотрите допишет ли ваш сервер кодировку когда отдавать будет. тогда станет ясно кто ее дописал. Если сервер - то искать строки с упоминанием charset, особенно AddDefaultCharset. Если не сервер - то хз. в описании header php в примерах в принципе без кодировки вроде отдает когда не указана

Comment: с расширением `*.html` отдает что надо, правда уже не `text/plain` как надо, а `text/html`

Answer (score 1):

1. Попробуйте использовать

   header_remove();
   header('Content-Type: text/plain');
2. В php.ini поищите строку типа `default_mimetype = "text/html; charset=windows-1251" и исправьте ее соответственно
3. Если в качестве фронтенда используется nginx, найдите в nginx.conf кодировку и исправьте ее, если она там установлена

   http {
       charset windows-1251;
   }
4. Если в качестве хоста используется apache, в conf/httpd.conf поищите и исправьте нечто вроде:

   AddDefaultCharset windows-1251

Comment: на счет второго пункта, эти настройки для `php` файлов, а вот когда я меняю расширение на `html`, какой файл отвечает за исполнение?

Comment: вы каким сервером отдаете? вот он и отвечает. apache, nginx+fpm, еще что-то. вам лучше знать, что у вас на компьютере происходит :) Для начала, можете сделать скрипт: <?php phpinfo(); ?> и посмотреть, что там написано (ну и заодним может быть, выложить сюда сохраненную htmlку, дабы люди подивились)